# How to actually submit data with twitter's typeahead

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead, typeahead.js

I'm using Twitter's typeahead frontend library for autocompletion. My configs use remote calls to the server. The autocompletion itself works fine, however the form tag refuses to actually input the content (after pressing enter) in the input tag now. I suspect it's because typeahead forces a  tag around the . Here is my code:

```
<form class="navbar-search form-search pull-left" action="javascript:query_main()" method="get">
    <div class="main_dropdown navbar-search">
       <input class="typeahead" id="query_main" type="text">
    </div>
</form>

Below is when the code worked (without typeahead)


<form class="navbar-search form-search pull-left" action="javascript:query_main()" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="query_main" class="main_dropdown typeahead">
</form>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a `data-provide="typeahead"` attribute in the input, like in the official doc example: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead

If you want to do something more complicated with the selected item, you could use the `updater` option in bootstrap's typeahead.

For instance, in your case, you would put something like this (in jQuery):

```
$('#query_main').typeahead({
    // Some options
    updater: function(item) {
        // Do something with item
        return item;
    },
    // Other options
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You should provide at least one `<input type="submit" />` in the form to expect the form to submit on pressing enter.

If you don't want the button to be shown, use CSS to hide it then.