# Bootstrap typeahead add value to hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using typeahead on my user database and everything seems to work fine. However, the search I am performing on is the last name of a member.

What I am trying to do is once a user is clicked on, instead of using the last name they entered into the field, I want to have it add the users ID to the field instead.

Is there a way to go about doing this?

```
$('input.query').typeahead({
    name: 'query',
    value: 'lastName',
    remote: 'jsonUser.php?query=%QUERY',
    minLength: 3,
    template: ["<div class='typeahead_wrapper'>", 
                "<img class='typeahead_photo' src='http://localhost/iwebimage.axd?qid={{qid}}'/>", 
                "<div class='typeahead_labels'>", 
                "<div class='typeahead_primary'>{{firstName}} {{lastName}} <small>({{ntid}})</small></div>", 
                "<div class='typeahead_secondary'>{{department}}</div>", 
                "</div>", 
                "</div>", ].join(''),

    engine: Hogan,
    limit: 8,
    valueKey: 'lastName'
});
```

UPDATE:

The JSON response contains the ID of the user, just not sure how to have the plugin use another value as the final value rather then what you are searching.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for him:

```
  $('input.query').on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {   

     console.log(datum['empID']); 
  });
```

I also found  [Bootstrap Typeahead updater not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331750/bootstrap-typeahead-updater-not-working) which recommends the same

NOTE: twitter are deprecating bootstrap/typhead and recommend that you use https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js with bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: bootstrap 3 no-longer supports updater. this answer only works for bootstrap 2 typeahead

[Overwrite the updater function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058661/how-to-actually-submit-data-with-twitters-typeahead) and add `data-provide="typeahead"` to the input

```
 $('input.query').typeahead({
     updater: function(item) {
        //item the json object that the user selected
        return item.id; // set input's value to item.id
      },
      //....
 )};
```

Html

```
<input class="query" data-provide="typeahead" />
```

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3 if it matters, had to use 

 $('input.query').on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {
     console.log(datum['empID']);
   });

Comment: nice but shouldn't have had to, they say to also put `data-provide="typeahead"` on the input, do you have that?

Comment: @Eru that typeahead functionality does not exist in Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

Add `valueKey: 'empID'` to your typeahead parameters and that will be the value put into the search box after you select an item from the typeahead